# Detect invalid login error for Parse user?

Tags: parse-platform

Is there any way to tell on the client side if a users credentials are invalid? When I intentionally break a users credentials (change username), they are getting an generic error 101 (kPFErrorObjectNotFound). How can I prompt a user to resolve a a legitimate account issue?

I get the security implications of oversharing with error codes, but even a general "something is wrong with authentication" would help. Maybe there's no harm is prompting after error 101, but I'm not when else that error is used.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a cloud function that you call and it checks if it has a user. If the user is correctly logged in then the passed token is converted into a user for the cloud code to access. Your cloud code can then return a simple response code which indicates if the login is valid or not.